# Can the width in css be selected dynamically with a variable

Tags: php, html, css

the code is :

```
<div class="bar">
    <div class="percentage" style="width:16%; height: 59px;">This is 66% wide div</div>
</div>
```

As you can see the width is 16 here....i need a way that it could be changed based on a variable like. I have a php query which returns a certain vale. And the width must be that vale. how can i do that?

Comment: `width=<?php echo $yourVariable; ?>%`

Comment: @Juhana should be `width:`, but yes.

Comment: Are you looking for a client-side solution, or server-side?

Comment: Get the data from server and display it on the web. The query gets a value from DB and needs to be displayed as a bar

Comment: @Gordon why did you remove the [php] tag from the question? The comments don't make sense now. And you didn't even correct the errors in the title.

Comment: @MrLister because the question is not related to PHP in any way

Comment: Server-side language is implied ("I have a query which returns a certain val[u]e") and the OP obviously needs a PHP solution.

Comment: There is nothing in the question text that justifies it to be tagged PHP. The OP does not mention it and server-side does not imply php only.

Comment: But it was about PHP! If I tag my question with [C++], but I don't mention the word C++ anywhere in my question, that doesn't mean you can come in and remove the tag!

Comment: The PHP tag *does* imply PHP only.

Comment: @MrLister wrong. if you dont mention c++ and dont include anything relating to c++ specifically then its not about c++. you are assuming it is. but it isnt. there is nothing in the question that asks for a php solution. again: serverside can be php, ruby, java, whatever.

Comment: Guys let it go....it is a php query. thats why i tagged php

Comment: @user fair enough then. but next time make sure you include all the relevant information in your text right from the start please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with Javascript. For example with JQuery:

```
$('.percentage').css({'width': x%, 'height': xpx});
```

or you can do it with PHP:

```
<div class="percentage" style="width: <?php echo $width; ?>%; height: <?php echo $height; ?>px; ">This is 66% wide div</div>
```

Comment: I think if the data comes from the server, doing it with server side code is more elegant and straightforward.

Comment: @user1424394 Well, the PHP. PHP runs on the server (i.e. the place where your website is stored) rather than the client (the place where it's displayed).

Comment: So i should graph it with php

Comment: ya got it.....but its not php code. Its just the html and css way of getting a bar. Do you know a simpler way to get using PHP only

Comment: Er... well, I suppose you can do something like `<?php $div_vble = "<div class... style="width: $width; ....` and then `echo $div_vble ?> `.